# does F3 correspond to any articulatory features?

Tags: phonetics

when describing vowels, increased F2 implies that the tongue is more front, and increased F1 implies that the tongue is more low. Does F3 correspond to anything, articulation wise?

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't map quite as nicely as height and frontness, but F3 is to some extent associated with **rounding**. For example, `[y]` (high front rounded vowel, not palatal approximant) has a much lower F3 than `[i]`.

Comment: Rounding is systematically associated with F2. F1 and F2 are sufficient to describe vowels. Sometimes, F3 fluctuates between a rounding vowel and a normal vowel, but I am not sure it is generalisable. An example from French: https://images.app.goo.gl/9df84ebuq2EGmvjQ6

Answer (score 7):

In rhotic varieties of English, F3 is lowered in r-colored vowels. It's not the only accoustic difference between r-colored and not-r-colored vowels, but it is there.